# ImportXML formula no longer working

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

Here is the formula:

```
=ImportXML("http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/7501:JP", "//div[@class='price-container down']//div[@class='price']")
```

As of several days ago, this formula stopped working. Why could this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong on Google's side, apparently. Other stock symbols import correctly. My uneducated guess is that there was a transmission error and a corrupted fetch result got stuck in Google's cache. I was able to break the cache by adding a redundant URL parameter: `http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/7501:JP?param=1` fetched correctly.

By the way, the selector `@class='price-container down'` will only fetch the price if it's going down, because otherwise the classes will be `price-contained up`. To fetch the data in either case, use `contains(@class,'price-container')` instead:

```
=ImportXML("http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/7501:JP?param=1", "//div[contains(@class,'price-container')]//div[@class='price']")
```

Comment: I appreciate this elegant solution, but still get the error message: "Could not fetch URL:  http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/7501:JP?param=1"

Comment: Indeed, now it doesn't work for me either.